# 正規表現 アポストロフィも文字列の一部としてマッチしたい。

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

正規表現のビギナーです。分かっていると思えるのは、\bが最初と最後のスペースだけマッチ。/gがグローバルで、一つだけではなく全てマッチする。\wがA-Z,a-z,0-9,_をマッチ。

理解が少し進んだのか、今のところアポストロフィをマッチングするための表現が合っていれば[\']?を入れる場所です。

しかしとすると、var arr = str.match(/\b(\w+|\')\b/g);

[ 'Hell', '\'', 'o', 'World' ]と出力します。

結果として出したいのは['Hell'o',　'World']です。

```js
function countWords(str) {
  var count = 0;
  var arr = str.match(/\b(\w+)[^']\b/g);
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] != ""){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
countWords("Hell'o　World ")
```

Comment: 対象の文字列が`Hell'o world`に対して、取り出したいのが`Hell'o`と`world`であれば「アポストロフィも文字列の一部として」マッチしたいになりそうですが、如何でしょうか。

Comment: @cubick  そうです。アポストロフィもマッチから除かれている(e.g. " ")のを除いてという事はマッチに含めたという事です。混乱してました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.match(/[\w']+/g);
```

これで良いような気がします。

半角スペースをデリミタとしてmatchしたいのであれば

```
str.match(/\S+/g);
```

でも良い気がします。

Comment: 単語の数だけ数えたいのでそれでも良いのですが、[ 'Hell\'o', 'World' ]のようにback slashが残っちゃうんですね。色々試してみます。

Comment: バックスラッシュの意味はご存知ですか？

Comment: \’ で本当は’だけ出るんじゃないんですか？

Comment: エスケープを理解されてるとして、質問に『バックスラッシュがどうしようとしたら、どこに、どのように表示されて問題』ということが書いてないと、ご希望の回答は付かないと思います。もし解決すべき内容であるなら、別の質問を作られた方が良いと思います。元々の質問内容と大きく変わってしまうので...

Comment: ありがとうございます。まず色々自分でトライしてみたいと思います。