# 正規表現の表示に関するオンラインエディタの特徴について

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

[正規表現 アポストロフィも文字列の一部としてマッチしたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40000/%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE-%E3%82%A2%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AD%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%82%82%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E9%83%A8%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/40005?noredirect=1#comment40562_40005)　に少し関連して、以下のコードでsingle quoteをエスケープできるようになりました。しかし、僕が使っているrepl.itでは、

/[w']+/g
 [ 'Hell\'o', 'World' ]
/[^s]+/g
 [ 'Hell\'o', 'World' ]

と出力されるようです。オンラインエディタによってはエスケープしているように解釈しなきゃいけないようです。(rendering artifactと呼ばれている）質問はオンラインエディタで、正規表現初心者でこのようにエスケープなどで誤解しやすい様になっているものはありますか？

```js
function printWords(str) {
  var count = 0;
  var arr = str.match(/[\w']+/g);
  console.log("/[\w']+/g\n", arr);
}
printWords("Hell'o　World ");

function printWordss(str) {
  var count = 0;
  var arr = str.match(/[^\s]+/g);
  console.log("/[^\s]+/g\n", arr);
}
printWordss("Hell'o　World ")
```

edit1:

コメントの依頼からrendering artifactの用語について、https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006095/escaping-regex-single-quote-creates-extra-backslashes-on-repl-it　の回答者のコメントより。

Comment: おっしゃっているrendering artifactについて参照されたページなどあれば追記して下さい

Comment: @todashuta 追記しました。

Comment: @kimiTanaka その "rendering artifact" というのは言語処理系の専門用語ではないように思います。ここでいう artifact というのは[この回答](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/106528/257670)に書かれた意味に近いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご質問の意図がよく分かりません。repl.it で表示される文字列がエスケープされているのは、単にそのような処理になっているからでしょう。repl.it と同じようにエスケープして表示するサイトを知りたいということでしょうか？　それともエスケープの他にひっかかりそうなポイントを教えてほしいということでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 正規表現のマッチング自体をrepl.itのサイトのようにsingle quoteをrendering artifactで表現するようなのは、オンラインエディタで良くあり、正規表現ビギナーは気をつけるべきなのかと言うことです。backslash(/) や hat(^) がrendering artifactで残ったりするのかなと。そうすると、rendering artifactの概念に慣れないといけないかも知れないですね。

Comment: 何が問題で、何を解決したいのかが分かりません。雑談したいだけのようにも見えるんですが。。。そうするとこのサイトの趣旨とは異なってしまいます。エスケープ自体は別にオンラインエディタだけの特徴では無く、言語において必ずと言っていいほど定義されている仕様ですよ。

Comment: @豚吐露 それははっきりと違うと思います。くだらない質問ではないと思います。自分で問題点をはっきりするために質問しました。定義の解釈、齟齬がないかを確認するのも重要だと思います。

Comment: ご自分の中では問題がはっきりされているようですが、他の方に伝わっていないように思います。正規表現のエスケープとJavaScriptのエスケープは別物です。正規表現には正規表現のエスケープが、JavaScriptにもJavaScriptのエスケープが存在し、同じ物ではありません。その辺を理解なさって質問内容を編集すると所望の回答が付くようになるかと思います。

Comment: @豚吐露 豚吐露さんのご意見でご充分ですので回答にしてくだされば、また詳しく自分で確認しようと思いますが、豚吐露さんの方が知見があり、専門家であるのでしょうし承認します。如何でしょうか？質問自体が雑談のように見えると言うのを回答に入れてもらった方が個人的には嬉しいのですがどうでしょう？もちろん、まだ質問自体が改善の余地があると思っいただいてコメントにして頂いたのかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 0):

nekketsuuuさんのコメントからするとsingle quoteのような文字リテラルをartifact扱いとし、正規表現でマッチングした後、single quoteをrendering artifactとして文字列として扱っているよう表現するようにrepl.itで採用されているようです。質問としては、正規表現で出力結果としてrendering artifactで表現するのはオンラインエディタでは良くあるものなのかと言うことでした。

以下抜粋 上記リンクより

> *semantics of artifact in software engineering*
>
> In graphics programming, its often used to reference part of an image
>   that did not render correctly. For example, if a small piece of a
>   previous frame or view is still left on screen after drawing is done,
>   that'd be referred to as an artifact.
>
> *rendering artifact in repl.it*
>
> That's a rendering artifact of how the REPL you are using represents a
>   string when it displays a string as the result of evaluating your
>   code.